# Ubuntu in docker GUI

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, docker

I am running docker containers with different distributions of linux ubuntu and centos. I am using docker for windows(it is running an image in virtualbox with docker linux). I cant find a way to run the gui of ubuntu.
How can I run the GUI. I am running with these:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"

docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock centos:latest sh -c "yum update ; yum install docker.io -y ; bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a noob at Linux, but try pressing the super (usually a Windows logo) key, then type docker and press enter (You have probably already tried that though)

Comment: :) I need to start the graphical user interface of the Ubuntu which is perfectly  running in a docker container on other host linux

Comment: I think you can try CTRL+ALT+F2, F3 or F4 to display command prompt, and F7 for Ubuntu GUI.